# How to disable verification step for all-auth? (sending verification email )

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I'm using all-auth (all-auth-rest) for basic authorization/authentication. By default, when the user register, Django all-auth is trying to send a verification email.

How can I disable it to prevent it from sending a verification email?

Comment: I think, ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none' or 'optional' in settings.py

Comment: You're right. Thanks :) Do you want to answer this question and get reputation point?

Comment: `none` does not send any email for verification, `optional` send verification email, but verification is not necessary to login, which means user can login without clicking on email.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think, ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none' or 'optional' in settings.py

Comment: `optional` only makes the verification not required but allauth still sends the email. `none` should be used to completely disable it.

Answer (score 16):

In `settings.py` add:

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
```

It will not send any email for verification.

*Reference:*  [django-allauth Configuration.](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html)